# How to limit the size of a Key in a Json response in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5kYF.png)
This is my JSON repsonse, there is an attribute (key) in the response named as **DATA** which is list of lists and have 1000+ list in it.

I want to limit the size of data(attribute inside json) to 30 lists and 90 lists for two different controllers. I am not able to find out how to do it.

Comment: You will need programatically (in your java implementation) to say exactly how to pick up only 30 elements(or 90) for your DTO(Data transfer object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract business logic to a `@Service` class, and provide the required limit as a parameter from a Controller:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

  MyDto createResponse(int limit) {
    //.... slice list size, e.g.
    List limitedData = data.subList(0, limit);
    //...
  }
}


@RestController
public class MyController1 {

  @Autowired
  MyService myService;

  MyDto createResponse() {
    return myService.createResponse(30);
  }
}



@Controller
public class MyController2 {

  @Autowired
  MyService myService;

  MyDto createResponse() {
    return myService.createResponse(100);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could look into [Pageable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html). This interface can be used to paginate data. This way you can return a subset of 30 items, but also display how many other pages there are